# 'fib' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, fibonacci

My execution lines in CMD are

```
D:\>cd jav 
D:\jav>javac fib.java  
D:\jav>fib java 

'fib' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I could not understand the problem here.As i done with settings in environment variables but still i get this command.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the command line round the wrong way. You want:

```
java fib
```

or preferably follow Java naming conventions, calling your class `Fib` rather than `fib`, and use

```
java Fib
```

(Even better, use packages - but that's probably the next step.)

When you compile a Java program, you end up with class files. That isn't a program which can just be launched from the command line - you have to start the JVM and tell *that* to launch your program... and that's what the `java` executable does.